# How is there no murder trial in Southpaw?

Tags: plot-explanation, southpaw

In the movie Southpaw, how is there no trial for the murder of Maureen? Given the presence of only a handful of people in the event and the bullet fragment/shell (and possible surveillance cameras), it would have been easy to investigate the murder and locate the killer. Why is the murder simply ignored, given it was a high profile killing?

Comment: (rant) The Law was keen on separating him from his child for his drunken driving but didn't seem to care about finding out who murdered his wife?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this deleted scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Azcoqtz7wG0) Billy Hope (Jake Gyllenhaal) talks to two police officers who are assigned to the case, they outline a few problems with evidence, meaning that they cannot find out who the killer is.

- As of the time they are working on the case (two weeks have passed)
  there is no video evidence of the shooting on cell phones or CCTV cameras
- There have been no eye witnesses to the shooting, including Billy
  himself who didn't see it, although claims Miguel Escobar's brother
  Hector was the one who did it.
- They say "No one is talking" and that they "Don't want to be involved"

For a trial to take place, the officers would have to gather evidence on one of the individuals and charge them. Because they have none, a trial would be out of the question. This explains why Miguel Escobar and his companions do not face any repercussions.

Comment: Thanks for that, the scene just makes it feel like even the cops don't want to side with Billy. Finding the bullet shell from the scene would have not been very tough. Further, tracing to the gun would be relatively simple given the attendees are known. The scene suggests that no shooting can lead to an arrest without eye witness.

Comment: However, it answers my question, even if the movie makers didn't think much about the trial. Thanks for that.

Answer (score -2):

there was actually but the hall was full of people there was not really eyewitness everyone was busy! it was Escobar's brother who shot her and i think there was a little scene about it Billy talking to the police & there is a deleted scene about it he was arguing with the police & they do nothing about it that's why he decides that he is gonna go kill Escobar brother's wife and than when he sees she's got kids he stops

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about the deleted scene, such as a link or a fuller description?

Comment: I would be eager to see this deleted scene too.